# Как передать параметр даты в sql запрос в репозитории

Tags: java, sql

Есть метод, он считывает строки из файла и записывает в базу:

```
Payment payment = new Payment();
        String[] parts = line.split(";");
        if (parts.length == 3) {
            // Это файл
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
            payment.setDate(dateFormat.parse(parts[0]));
            payment.setAccountInfo(parts[1]);
            payment.setAmount(new BigDecimal(StringUtils.prepareDecimalString(parts[2]))
                    .setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
                    //.divide(DIVISOR, RoundingMode.HALF_UP));
            return payment;
```

В файле есть дата, лицевой, и сумма. Могут попасться суммы с одним лицевым и одной датой, их необходимо просуммировать и записать в базу одно значение с одной датой.

```
BigDecimal fund = account.getFund();
        BigDecimal paymentAmount = payment.getAmount();
        payment.setPersonalAccount(account);
        account.setFund(fund.add(paymentAmount));
        paymentDate = payment.getDate();

        Optional<Payment> optionalPayment = paymentRepository.getPaymentForDate(account, paymentDate);
        if (optionalPayment.isPresent()) {
            Payment existingPayment = optionalPayment.get();
            existingPayment.setAmount(existingPayment.getAmount().add(paymentAmount));
            saveAccountAndPayment(existingPayment, account);
        } else {
            saveAccountAndPayment(payment, account);
        }
```

Но почему-то если попадаются суммы с одной датой, то ничего не суммируется, а просто в базу пишется одна из них. Вот код запроса:

```
@Query("select p from Payment p where (p.personalAccount = ?1) and (p.date = ?2)")
Optional<Payment> getPaymentForDate(PersonalAccount account, Date date);
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос используемую технологию для работы с БД. У вас hibernate? И покажите структуру БД - какие связи и как прописаны между таблицами. Скорее всего вы не так описали связь между таблицами.

Comment: Spring. По поводу неверных связей между таблицами это исключено. Да и тут в сущности откуда надо достать данные хранятся не ключи а именно значения. Т.е. она ни с чем по сути не связана. Я передаю в запрос значения которые в сущности есть, чтобы найти если такая запись имеется

Comment: В спринге с базой можно по разному работать. Желательно уточнить реализацию библиотеки для БД. Если у вас таки Hibernate, то таки покажите модельки и схему БД. Там всё работает очень сложно и порой проще написать нативный для используемого диалекта SQL запрос, чем пытаться его же сгенерировать через библиотеку. Также надо убедиться, что в БД схема нормальная и нормально транслируется в Java объекты. Я лично наблюдал проблемы со связями, приводившими к созданию колонок, которые в БД имели числовое значение, а в Java - объектное. В итоге запросы строить сложно.

Comment: Не сочтите за грубость, но причём тут связи. Это же не перекрестный запрос. Данные надо достать из одной сущности. Это всё равно как если бы вообще не было других таблиц кроме этой.

Comment: Меня смущает вот это в вашем запросе: `(p.personalAccount = ?1)` - не ясно как оно выглядит в схеме таблицы. Подозреваю, что именно в этом и есть проблема. Если бы вы показали как это выглядит в Java коде и как это же выглядит в схеме БД - многое могло бы проясниться

Comment: Это Spring Data JPA. Так в запрос передаются параметры. Но похоже суть проблемы куда глубже чем я думал. И по кускам кода мне вряд ли кто поможет

Comment: Вряд ли проблема глубока. Задача у вас вполне рядовая. Вопрос лишь в том, в какой в итоге SQL запрос транслируется ваш запрос на диалекте hibernate. Если бы вы включили в конфиге проекта вывод запросов в логи - то могли бы увидеть в чём проблема. Насколько я понимаю, у вас вообще ваш запрос не работает, значит он неправильно написан. Но я никогда не пробовал на этом диалекте писать, т.к. он слишком многое за программиста решает и всегда писал на диалекте конкретной БД - там полный контроль и всё ясно.